# Button Hover Override

Tags: c#, xaml, mouseenter

I have a button, as such:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Click="StartProcedure_Click" BorderThickness="0" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,1,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="resources\img_xraystarticon.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock TextElement.Foreground="#6a6869" Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Century Gothic">Start Procedure</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="resources\img_emptyrectbutton.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Where I applied the Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" style to remove the mouseover effects defaulting with the Button. However, I still continue to experience a mouseover effect, as shown here:

[image]

Prior to Mouseover, and with Mouseover:

[image]

I have attempted to override the MouseEnter event with no success (I have confirmed my MouseEnter event is triggered but I can't seem to negate the property that is set with MouseEnter by default with the above).

What do I need to do to avoid the above?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have entered the below code but I am now unable to get a MouseEnter function to execute properly (I want the text to change colors but I am not seeing it happen):

```
<Button Name="Button_StartMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Click="StartProcedure_Click" BorderThickness="0" Height="60" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="10,1,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="True" MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="resources\img_emptyrectbutton.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="resources\img_xraystarticon.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                <TextBlock TextElement.Foreground="#6a6869" Padding="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Century Gothic"><Run Text="Start Procedure"/></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to 'prevent' it I would define the mouseover event to display the same as the non-mouseover.  You can set them both to be the same and while it will still switch, visually it appears the same.

[How do you change Background for a Button MouseOver in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259280/how-do-you-change-background-for-a-button-mouseover-in-wpf)

```
       <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
```

Comment: I updated my above code which got rid of the mouseenter effect of highlighting but it now prevents any mouseenter effect from taking hold, even when I am calling Button_StartMenu.Foreground = Brushes.Green from MouseEnter..

Comment: You'll have to set that in the trigger section.  You can make a style that can be reused instead of putting all the properties on this specific button.

Comment: Even if I enclose the Style.Triggers into my property for the button, I am still having the same issue - it doesn't trigger with the above code. Your code above doesn't help with it.

Comment: Sorry that's the best I can do.  I know how much of these things are supposed to work, but I usually need some trial and error to get everything to work as expected.

Comment: Well, have an upvote for helping, at least. I'll continue playing with it.

Comment: Thanks!  And sorry it wasn't more help.

Comment: What about for Windows Universal? Style.triggers are no longer present.