# How can i add a transition when changing style of a wpf tool?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I am designing an app in C# using WPF. I want to add a hover effect. When the user hovers on the button I want to increase its left border thickness.
I did it by using the following method. But I want to add a transition of 1 second. I am stuck with it!!

````
        {
            
                btn1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10, 1, 1, 1);
            
           } 
        ```
````

Comment: In Wpf, it would make more sense to do the designs in the designer instead of the code-behind. You can use the Style property to style it the way you want when hovered over it. Here is a small example. Of course you should add something on top of it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259993/14875740

Comment: In addition, I recommend you to research the concepts of EventTrigger and Storyboard.

Comment: I have basic concept of EventTriggers and StoryBoards. But they just change it from one state to another. i want to add a transition. Lets say i want to increase the font size from 14px to 30px. I want it to change in 2 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You may animate a Thickness by a ThicknessAnimation.

```
btn1.BeginAnimation(
    Button.BorderThicknessProperty,
    new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(10, 1, 1, 1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
```

Comment: ThicknessAnimation is underlined in red.

Comment: And the IDE shows you an error message about a missing namespace. Click on the light bulb or press `Ctrl`+`.` - Visual Studio will suggest to add the missing `using` directive.